# CQL Select on column value

Tags: cassandra, cql

I am creating account data in Cassandra.  Accounts are most commonly queried based on an account id.  However, often the account is queried by a login name.  I have created a user table with primary keys (account_id and login_name).  Because of this, I have to "ALLOW FILTERING" on the table to query by the login_name.

Is there a better way to create the table that does not have the impact of a filterable table?

Answer (score 3):

A possible approach is to define a new table that has the exact same elements in the primary key but in the reverse order: `(login_name, account_id)`. You can still keep the table you present as the reference table, which stores all the relevant account data, but this new table would allow you more optimized queries based on `login_name`. I am not sure how much you would win compared with the query "allowing filtering"... But this kind of "data duplication" for query optimization is a normal procedure in NoSQL DBs.

HTH.